# fgetcsv() unable to recognize comma after UTF-8 character?

Tags: php, csv

We have a large CSV file that we read via **fgetcsv**():

```
$row = fgetcsv($this -> handle, null, ',', '"');
```

Which is all fine until one of the rows look like this:

```
The Parkway Dentist - We Can See U Now™,https://www.xxxx.com,together@xxxx.com,(817) 735-xxxx, ,4200,Benbrook,TX,76109,"Benbrook,TX 76109","Cosmetic Dentistry, Dentists, Endodontists, Implant Dentistry, Teeth Whitening Products & Services",, , , ,valid,the-parkway-dentist-we-can-see-u-now-465117871,32.69415,-97.41237,https://instagram.com/xxxx,https://www.facebook.com/xxxx, ,,
```

Which is parsed by **fgetcsv**() like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => The Parkway Dentist - We Can See U Now鈩?https://www.xxxx.com
    [1] => together@xxxx.com
    [2] => (817) 735-xxxx
    [3] =>
    [4] => 4200
    [5] => Benbrook
    [6] => TX
    [7] => 76109
    [8] => Benbrook,TX 76109
    [9] => Cosmetic Dentistry, Dentists, Endodontists, Implant Dentistry, Teeth Whitening Products & Services
    [10] =>
    [11] =>
    [12] =>
    [13] =>
    [14] => valid
    [15] => the-parkway-dentist-we-can-see-u-now-465117871
    [16] => 32.69415
    [17] => -97.41237
    [18] => https://instagram.com/xxxx
    [19] => https://www.facebook.com/xxxx
    [20] =>
    [21] =>
    [22] =>
)
```

Clearly **fgetcsv**() doesn't get the comma delimiter after the first field thus mistakenly glues the 1st and 2nd field together while they should be apart as 2 different fields.

The only thing we find different is the UTF-8 character immediately before the comma delimiter.

How can we make **fgetcsv**() to correctly recognize the situation here?

## UPDATE

PHP version is 7.0.10. According to Notepad++, the CSV file is in UTF-8-BOM encoding. Tried this code:

```
$line = fgets($this -> handle, 1048576);
print_r(mb_detect_encoding($line, 'UTF-8', true));
```

Which output:

```
UTF-8
```

So it seems the file is UTF-8 no problem.

You can see the CSV file containing the problematic line here: http://n3.datasn.io/utf8-problem.csv

I tested this file just now with this code:

```
$row = fgetcsv($this -> handle, null, ',', '"');
print_r($row);
```

Which still output the first field value as:

```
The Parkway Dentist - We Can See U Now鈩?https://www.xxxx.com
```

Comment: is the file definitely encoded in utf-8? is your php script? ihas your html got a utf8 meta tag?

Comment: To better answer this question, it would be helpful to see the output of `hexdump -C` of that line in the csv.

Comment: I suspect that you may have a UTF-16 file, not UTF-8, but the error could still be possible.  PHP UTF support is not particularly good, so you may need to use `fread` and `mb_convert_encoding($str , 'UTF-8' , 'UTF-16LE');` in conjunction with `str_getcsv` to process non ISO/IEC 8859-1 or UTF-8 files.

Comment: Docs warn about locale settings being taken into account by this function. Do you set yours or just rely on system default?

Comment: @delboy1978uk yes, according to Notepad++ the file is UTF8 with BOM.

Comment: @Evert How to specify the line number? It's a huge 170MB csv file it's not easy to locate to the screen of the exact line for hexdump -C

Comment: What is your output from `echo setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 0);`?

Comment: @MattRaines It's "Chinese (Simplified)_China.936" -- this could be the culprit?

Comment: @AlexBarker Tried your suggestion but `mb_convert_encoding($line , 'UTF-8' , 'UTF-16LE')` seems to be messing the first row to something not recognizable at all. And this `$line = fgets($this -> handle, 1048576); print_r(mb_detect_encoding($line, 'UTF-8', true));` gives `UTF-8`. Seems it's actually UTF-8 no problem?

Comment: You may try `ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', "none");`
`$text= mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');` as in comment https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#108643
I assume it should remove symbol if it is not valid utf-8 character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a note in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), "The locale settings are taken into account by this function. If LC_CTYPE is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encodings may be read wrongly by this function."

You have the opposite problem. You are trying to read a UTF-8 file but your locale settings use a different encoding. Your LC_CTYPE of "Chinese (Simplified)_China.936" uses the [Code page 936 (Simplified Chinese)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_936_(Microsoft_Windows)) encoding so `fgetcsv` is unable to open UTF-8 files unless you change your locale.

You can do this on a per-process basis with (for example) `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');` if the `en_US.UTF-8` locale is installed on your system — but read the warning on the [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) about how this can affect other scripts running on the server — or change the [intl.default-locale](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.configuration.php#ini.intl.default-locale) setting in your `php.ini`.